# How To Include a cookie-id when tracking events

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am completely new to Google Tag Manager.  I have gotten it installed on my site, and it is working to count the number of clicks on the register button.

However, what I really want to do is this:

1. A user lands on the page. I want to place a tracking cookie for the user, and then log the page view along with the tracking cookie ID.
2. The user then clicks the register button.  I then want to track the click event along with the tracking cookie ID.

By including the tracking cookie information, I can then easily see that User A landing on the Page at 10:00, and then at 10:02 Clicked on the Register Button.

It gives a clear picture of what happened on the site.  My goal is to drive people to the site through adwords, but I then need to see exactly what happened with these people and how long they were on the site.

Can I do this with GTM/Google Analytics?  If so, how?  If not, is there some other tool for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [User Explorer report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en) in Google Analytics.